# Why my eclipse need to export v7.jar and v4.jar?

Tags: android

Now，I use  eclipse for android，but it has some questions if  not to export  v7.jar and v4.jar.Can you tell me why?

Comment: First things first, move to Android Studio. It is 2017 for God's sake

Answer (score 0):

just read this

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html

and Google already dropped support for Eclipse Android Developer Tool, so move to Android Studio